# iOS 14 Universal Links broken on default browser other than Safari

Tags: mobile-safari, ios14, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

On iOS 14 you can pick another default browser than Safari. If you use another browser, that browser will ask the user to change their default browser.

I have installed quite a few browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, Brave...) and have set each of them as my default one.

Problem comes when I try to open a Universal Link (which was working just fine when Safari was the default browser), which seems to just not work. With Safari as default browser, the Universal Link would work, and the corresponding native app was getting opened. However, with any other browser different from Safari set as default, the feature is broken and the Universal Link doesn't open the native app.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?
Why might this happen and how might this be solved?

Any help is very much welcomed

Answer (score 4):

**For iOS 14+**

I suggest to add this to your Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>https</string>
</array>
```

By adding this you can continue to use method canOpenURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com") else { return }
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug on iOS up until 14.1, have you checked this?
https://www.komando.com/gadgets/apple-releases-ios-14-1/754697/

Edit: works for me