# iOS : Universal links are not working when set default browser is Chrome/brave(other then safari)

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, ios-universal-links, brave

In our iOS universal links for our app is not opening our application when we tap on the link. This is happening only when the default browser in iPhone is set to Chrome or brave (other than safari).

It works perfectly when default browser is safari.

By the way we have all the set-up for both iOS app and web server configured properly.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Expected behaviour would be launch the app when default iPhone browser is Chrome or brave.

**We tried these below options, none of them worked**
[iOS 14 Universal Links broken on default browser other than Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572364/ios-14-universal-links-broken-on-default-browser-other-than-safari)

Comment: Hi @nagaraju, did you find any solution for this? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Did you guys find anything here?